# sqlalchemy random seed per sql query

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am looking for a way to order the results of an sqlalchemy query randomly, however I want the random order to be consistent for each user based on lets say a token.

```
q = q.order_by(func.random())
```

Note: I'm using postgresql

I found that I can use `select setseed(0)` and union all with the result of the query and then offset by 1, however that assumes that I know the number of columns `q` will have (which I could probably find out), but it sounds like a very bad practice to hardcode the number of columns especially for maintainability.

Is this the right approach? If so, is there a way to dynamically get the number of columns of a query? If not, what would be the correct approach?

Answer (score -1):

you can use inspect to get the number of columns

something like:

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect
url=YOUR_DB_URL
engine = create_engine(url, convert_unicode=True, echo=False)
inspector = inspect(engine)
schemas = inspector.get_schema_names() #(If you need to find the names of the schemas)
number_of_cols= len(inspector.get_columns(YOUR_TABLE_NAME, schema=SCHEMA_NAME))
```